# Pass playbook to ansible-playbook by argument

Tags: ansible

As far I see `ansible-playbook` expects at least one argument - the name of the file that contains the playbook (YAML content).

E.g.

```bash
ansible-playbook -i myinventory.ini myplaybook.yml
```

Is it possible to pass the playbook completely by argument?

E.g.

```bash
ansible-palybook -i myinventory.ini -XYZ "content of my playbook here"
```